# Не работает logout в Symfony 6.3

Tags: php, symfony, сессия

Есть сайт на symfony 6.3. Когда разрабатывал его локально на localhost в docker проблемы вроде небыло. Но вот как только перенёс на купленный домен на сервер появилась проблема.
Тут нужно сказать, что доменная зона моего домена .in.net, т.е. домен имеет вид:

```
domain.in.net
```

На сайте имеется вход только через соц. сети. И вот сам вход на сайт работает отлично - я получаю от соц. сети данные, пишу в базу и логиню юзера. А вот выход не получается никак - мучаюсь уже второй день. Вот мои конфиги:
security.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        fetcher:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: fetcher
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            custom_authenticator:
                - App\Security\OAuth\GithubAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\FacebookAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\GoogleAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\InstagramAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\LinkedinAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\MicrosoftAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\YahooAuthenticator
            # entry_point: App\Security\OAuth\GithubAuthenticator

            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: team


            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_USER

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/dashboard/adminka, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Здесь нужно отметить, что при переходе на роут app_logout (указанный в path:) происходит редирект на роут team (указанный в target:), но разлогина не происходит. Юзер так и остаётся залогиненным. Но вот путь /logout symfony перехватывает как и должно быть.

Ещё во framework.yaml пробовал добавлять:
cookie_domain: domain.in.net
но проблему это не решило

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false
    handle_all_throwables: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        cookie_domain: domain.in.net # Here specify my domain name
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

Ещё заметил, что если очистить кэш браузера, то можно зайти и затем выйти из аккаунта корректно. Но вот если после этого зайти повторно выйти уже не получается.
При переходе на /logout сессия так и остаётся висеть в cookie, хотя перенаправляет на роут указанный в target: team
Это что баг в symfony? Перерыл весь интернет, такой проблемы больше не встречал.

Comment: возможно, ты забыл добавить роут в `config/routes.yaml`, внимательно читай документацию https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out